# Looking for USA roads traffic load data

Tags: google-maps, data, united-states

I would like to make a map of the USA Roads with traffic load data (I don't care if it updates monthly , quarterly...) in order to analyze location of customer's shops (they sell vehicle parts and want to see how close their / competitors stores are to high traffic roads)

What I'm looking for is :

1. Average Load
2. Peak Load

I don't know which resolutions are available but of course I would like to have the best there is (hope for free :)  )

I need the entire USA roads highways & main roads are most important.
the more data I have the better my map will be for my client.

Any idea where I can get such data ? I would like to have end result like this (color wise) :

[image]

Comment: Average? Peak? Resolution in spatial and temporal sense? Is all of US a requirement? Down to what level of road?

Comment: Both average and peak, resolution is the best I can get and about roads, the most I can get - Highway and major roads are most important. If I can get more roads, it will be better

Comment: Can you say what you want it for?

Comment: @BradHards - I've edited the question with the reason. Thank you.